# how to clean out the catkin tree for different build type

Tags: ros, catkin, ros-groovy, build

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How or what do you do to clean out a build of the catkin tree so that a different build can be done?
I installed catkin workspace tree with the desktop-full packages for groovy.  That build has build problem with fulle*.  So I thought that I would start at the other end of the scale and build the ros-comm tree first.  I am trying to build on a raspberry pi system.  We have Fuerte built and running on it.  I am also developing the build instructions for this in the wiki tree.  I am coming to the result that I need to put together a cross-compilier enviroment to speed up the builds.  With 500,000 sold in less than one year and a cost of $65.00 for a headless linux system. That doing this would be useful since I am working with the cube-spawn project to set up a multiple cube manufacturing environment.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/51537/how-to-clean-out-the-catkin-tree-for-different-build-type/) by [bobt](https://answers.ros.org/users/3863/bobt/) on ROS Answers with karma: 65 on 2013-01-05

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can always delete a build folder in catkin and create a new one. You can also have differently named build folders. Catkin always builds all packages it finds in the src folder, so if you only want to build the ros_comm variant, you need to remove all packages that do not belong to that variant from the src folder.

If you need a "make clean" command that removes all items from your buildspace (and devel space) but keeps your build options i don't think we have such a thing, nor does cmake. But your buildspace is like a standard cmake build space.

So you can remove the devel folder, and remove all files and folders from your build folder except for CMakeCache.txt (which contains your build options). Calling cmake then will start a fresh build.
So step-by-step:

- remove undesired projects from src folder
- delete devel folder
- delete anything within build folder except for CMakeCache.txt

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2013-01-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nwb234](https://answers.ros.org/users/3617/nwb234/) on 2014-07-31**:
Suppose you deleted the CMakeCache.txt from the build directory as well, is there anyway to recover it short of running catkin_init_workspace?